# Invert Fly Mode Mouse Control?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

When using Fly mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the 3D view),
moving the mouse up rotates up, and moving down rotates down. Is it possible to invert this so moving the mouse to the bottom of the screen rotates up?

Comment: Not sure if you can customize that via User Preferences... maybe possible, wait for other to answer, I guess. However, when in Fly Mode, I usually use AWSD keyboard button, instead of relying on Mouse gesture direction.

Comment: change blender navigation to keyboard? something like unreal?

Comment: @KauêLima It's been a while since I've used unreal, if it is something like typical FPS controls (wasd + mouselook) then you might be interested in [walk navigation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html#walk-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In 2.82 it's found under Preferences -> Navigation -> Fly & Walk -> Reverse Mouse.

[image]

However this only affects Walk, not Fly.

Answer (score 3):

Using the macOS version of Blender v2.80 & v2.82a the settings can be found under *Preferences -> Navigation -> Natural Trackpad Direction*.

[image: Natural scroll]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is *not* possible out of the box with Blender. In *Fly mode*, the camera follows the direction of the mouse cursor and rotates accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>R</kbd> to translate up and <kbd>F</kbd> to translate down if the mouse gestures feel odd.

Comment: R/F translate up/down, rather then rotating the view (mouselook). so it works but not really equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In newest version, *Edit > Preferences > Navigation > Natural trackpad direction*

Comment: I couldn't find this setting in 2.81, but I do see there is now a *Reverse Mouse* setting under *Preferences > Navigation > Fly and Walk > Walk* which does what I want.